# How to set keybinding in Neovim with 'Ctrl+/'

Tags: lua, neovim, keymapping

Here is part of my config

```
local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
local keymap = vim.api.nvim_set_keymap
keymap("n","<C-/>",":lua require('Comment.api').toggle_current_linewise()<CR>" ,opts)
keymap("n","<a-/>",":lua require('Comment.api').toggle_current_linewise()<CR>" ,opts)
```

keymap with `alt` works but with `ctrl` does not.
I have other commands with `ctrl` and all of them work except this one

```
:verbose map <C-/>
    n  <C-/>       * :lua require('Comment.api').toggle_current_linewise()<CR>                                                                                                                                                       
            Last set from ~/.config/nvim/init.lua
```

Any idea why it is not working ??

Comment: Which terminal are you using? Sequences such as Ctrl+/ are not recognized by all terminals, so this might explain why it's not working for you...

Comment: I got the solution, to map `/` we should use `<c-_>` instead of `<c-/>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To map `/`: use `<C-_>` instead of `<C-/>`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @Borjovsky Looks like now `<C-/>` works for Ctrl+/, but `<C-_>` does not. I have 0.9.0-dev-793+g7126d9b8c on Windows.